# What PoW hashing algorithms did Monero historically use?

Tags: cryptonight, proof-of-work

Originally, Monero used the Cryptonight PoW algorithm, then started modifying it to thwart ASICs getting large parts of the network hash rate.

What is the timeline of these changes ?

Answer (score 5):

Monero's genesis block dates back from April 2014. The first PoW change was in 2018.

The full history is:

```
| block   | date       | PoW algorithm
|---------|------------|--------------
| 0       | 2014-04-18 | Cryptonight (retroactively CNv0)
| 1546000 | 2018-04-06 | Cryptonight variant 1 (CNv1)
| 1685555 | 2018-10-18 | Cryptonight variant 2 (CNv2)
| 1788000 | 2019-03-09 | Cryptonight variant 4 (CNv4)
| 1978433 | 2019-11-30 | RandomX
```

Monero switched to RandomX in November 2019, a new PoW algorithm not based on Cryptonight, which is based on the premise of random code execution.